# Add AntiForgeryToken to Asp.Net MVC form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csrf, csrf-protection

I need to add **AntiForgeryToken** to my application. I've done following:

1. Add AntiForgeryToken to view:

> ```
> <form id="client-group-details-form" action="" method="post">
> <%Html.AntiForgeryToken(); %>
> //Rest of the form
> <form>
> ```

2. Add `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute to specific methods in controller

I need to do this also which I'm unable to find out how:

3. Add `_RequestVerificationToken` value to the data sent back to server. What does it mean and How can I do it?

Comment: Who knows, maybe wanna tell us where did you get that information? Using Html helper and the attribute on corresponding controller action should be enough AFAIK.

Comment: `<%Html.AntiForgeryToken(); %>` adds a hidden input for `__RequestVerificationToken`. You dont need to do anything else

Answer (score 0):

When you add `<%Html.AntiForgeryToken(); %>` _RequestVerificationToken value will automatically be added to the data that you sent back in the POST request. There is nothing else that needs to be done.
First check in the POST data, if you see that value or not.

Comment: Not so, you must also add the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute to the action you're posting to.

Answer (score 0):

To implement antiforgerytoken you need to do two steps
1) Add this line in View
2) Add this line action

Otherthings will be done by asp.net mvc

for details: http://innerexception.org/posts/t50-What-is-the-anti-forgery-token-in-asp-net-mvc